# Let Gradle update/change its dependencies after targetSDK version change

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

If I have a project in Android Studio and at the beginning my gradle application file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.indapond.hellotoast"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

If I now change the `compileSdkVersion` and the `targetSdkVersion` to something else, let's say 26,
I get an error - since my `appcompat` -dependency is not working for that sdk-version.  How can I let Android Studio/Gradle change it's dependencies automatically according to the SDK-Version?
So far, I have to look-up the correct Version of appcompat for my target sdk and change it by hand. I hate that.

Comment: We all hate that. I'm not aware of any out of the box solution. What I do, though, is put those numbers closer together in an ext block so it's easier to change them simultaneously.